# Given 2 unsorted arrays and a sum, give two numbers that, when added, equal the sum

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

In these arrays, the numbers can be either positive or negative.
Only one number from each array may be used.

I received this question as an algorithms question on a phone interview and it stumped me. The interviewer seemed to believe there was an O(n) solution.

Edit: My question is different than the "possible duplicates" because this question involves 2 arrays, rather than one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a pair of elements from an array whose sum equals a given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unsorted arrays - fill hash table with the first array values and walk through the second one, checking if `Sum-B[i]` exists in the table

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need more practice with questions that expect you to implement a hash table.